# Не могу понять, где ошибка в коде Python и как её исправить, чтобы всё заработало?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Пишу простого бота вк, который будет приветствовать всех, кто вступил в чат. Вот код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="73dd404e6817130085226a4cde7e5c165bd790144d8ef019a119bffd6bf6cc3d8012f521398e5da8d9b79")
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 202315194)


def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.from_chat:

            id = event.chat_id
            msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()

            try:
                dey = event.message.action['type']
                invite_id = event.message.action['member_id']
            except:
                dey = ""
                invite_id = -100

            if dey == 'chat_invite_user':
                sender(id, f'Приветствую тебя, @id{invite_id}!')
            if msg == 'привет':
                sender(id, 'приветствую')
```

PyCharm выдаёт следующее:

```
Shadows built-in name 'id' 9
Shadows name 'id' from outer scope 9
Shadows built-in name 'id' 17
PEP 8: E722 do not use bare 'except' 23
Too broad exception clause 23
```

Помогите разобраться с ошибками и дописать код, чтобы всё работало.

Answer (score 2):

Это предупреждения, а не ошибки:

- исправьте название переменной `id` на какое-нибудь другое - `PyCharm` вас предупреждает, что это название переменной перекрывает встроенную функцию `id`
- сделайте название первого параметра функции `sender` другим, не таким, как название переменной в основной части программы
- укажите конкретное исключение, которое вы ловите в `except:`, например `except Exception:`

Насчёт `unindent` непонятно, возможно у вас смешаны табуляции и пробелы, отступы вроде нормальные.

Comment: изменил id, выровнял код, но не понял, что именно нужно с 'except' сделать.
Можно прям пример с моим кодом, чтобы логику бота сохранить

Comment: Ошибки:
'Shadows name 'id_msg' from outer scope 9
PEP 8: E722 do not use bare 'except' 23
Too broad exception clause 23'

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Также, вам советую поменять токен, дабы злоумышленники не смогли им воспользоваться.